# Session is not working properly

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

On my asp.net 2.0 website ,when i logged in site having url like http://xxxxx.com/login.aspx, it create user session but after login when i goto specific page having url like http://www.xxxxx.com/page.aspx session is out ,Remember both pages are on same domain.what i got, i think issue is of redirecting "http" to "http://www" .
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's just how cookies work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is exactly as you suspect one of sub domains. I suggest you redirect to www. first and host your login page there.